# How to redirect users to app on the App Store from push notification alert?

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-push-notifications, parse-platform

I'm using parse sdk for pushing notification in my iphone application, so what I want to do is to promote my other apps through the push notification alerts, I mean when the user tap the view button on the notification it will launch my app and redirect him/her to another app of mine on the App Store. I saw some apps doing that, so does anybody know how to implement that?
Any help will be appreciated , thanks.

Comment: Are you sure those apps were using Parse to do the URL redirect?  I know that functionality comes built in with PushWoosh.  Were you able to get Wain's solution to work?

Answer (score 2):

Your best options is to add custom URL schemes to all of your apps and in the push notification send:

1. The app iTunes id
2. The app custom URL scheme

Now, when you receive the notification, check if the app can open the URL scheme (`UIApplication -canOpenURL:`). If it can, open it, don't bother with the store. If it can't, use `SKStoreProductViewController` with the iTunes id to display a store inside your app (without having to open the app store app).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Can you please tell me how to add custom URL schemes to all of my apps with details ? Please.

Comment: Thanks I will try the search url you provided.

Comment: Do I need to write the notification in json or just put the app id? Can you please give me an example?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The push from parse should have 2 pieces of information (kay/value pairs).

Comment: What I mean if you can give me a  written example of the push notification, how will it look like?